# Kruskal alghoritm - working but difficult

Tags: c, linked-list, kruskals-algorithm

I was working on Kruskal algorithm that will read input and based on this information it will find the shortest path between every two nodes.

Let me explain:
There are numbers on the input, for example:

```
7 6 1 5
1 7 20
7 2 5
2 3 9
4 2 4
5 2 7
6 5 3
```

On the first line there are 4 numbers = number of nodes, number of edges, beginning node (where to start), end node (where to end).

On the rest of lines are 3 numbers = one node(lets say x), second node(y), length between them.

The input will give me shortest path between the start and end node.

In this example case it would be number 32.

I have a fully working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct edge{
    int goal, length;
    struct edge *p_next;
} EDGE;

typedef struct node{
    int name;
    EDGE *p_edges, *last;
} NODE;

int helper;

int getDist(int size, NODE *nodes[size+1], int from, int act, int goal)
{
    EDGE *p_act;

    for(p_act = nodes[act]->p_edges; p_act != 0; p_act = p_act->p_next)
    {
        if (p_act->goal == goal)
        {
            return p_act->length;
        }
        if (p_act->goal != from)
        {
            helper = getDist(size, nodes, act, p_act->goal, goal);
        }
        if (helper != 0)
        {
            return helper + p_act->length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int numV, numH, start, goal, i, length, a, b;
    EDGE *p_newEdge, *p_newEdge2;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &numV , &numH, &start, &goal);
    NODE *nodes [numV+1];

    for(i = 0; i <= numV; i++)
    {
        nodes[i] = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    }
    for(i = 0; i < numH; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&length);
        p_newEdge = (EDGE*)malloc(sizeof(EDGE));
        p_newEdge->length = length;
        p_newEdge->goal = b;
        p_newEdge2 = (EDGE*)malloc(sizeof(EDGE));
        p_newEdge2->length = length;
        p_newEdge2->goal = a;
        if (nodes[a]->p_edges == 0)
        {
            nodes[a]->p_edges = p_newEdge;
            nodes[a]->last = p_newEdge;
        }
        else if (nodes[a]->p_edges != 0)
        {
            nodes[a]->last->p_next = p_newEdge;
            nodes[a]->last = nodes[a]->last->p_next;
        } 
        if (nodes[b]->p_edges != 0)
        {
            nodes[b]->last->p_next = p_newEdge2;
            nodes[b]->last = nodes[b]->last->p_next;
        }
        else if (nodes[b]->p_edges == 0)
        {
            nodes[b]->p_edges = p_newEdge2;
            nodes[b]->last = p_newEdge2;
        }        
    }
    printf("%d\n",getDist(numV ,nodes, 0, start, goal));
    return 0;
}
```

But my professor told me that it is very long and I should make it more simple (this was my third attempt and for my professor it is still too long and "complex").

I have no idea how to make it more simple.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The code looks nice. I would 1. Go with `NODE *nodes = malloc(sizeof(NODE) * (numV + 1));` or `NODE nodes[numV+1];`. Using VLA for pointers and malloc for memory is a strange mix. 2. Remove double ifs. ` if (nodes[a]->p_edges == 0) {} else if (nodes[a]->p_edges != 0) {}` The second if is just repeating itself. Maybe get what indentation style your profesor uses on lectures and mimic it. Also the member `node->name` appears to be unused. Also the two newEdge malloc could be a function - both do the same think, one assigns to node [a], the second to node [b].

Comment: Kruskal's algorithm generate a minimum spanning tree.  You appear to be finding a shortest path.  Maybe you mean Dijkstra's algorithm?